# pyinotify-- no space left on device

Tags: linux, python3

python 3.7 / Ubuntu 18.10

Getting this error setting up a watch using pyinotify. It happens for any directory I've tried.

This started after I installed pcloud but pcloud is not touching this directory.

```
 pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch 
/home/stephen/<watchtarget> WD=-1, Errno=No space left on 
device (ENOSPC)
```

`df -h` shows no mounts are close to full.

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
 tmpfs           1.6G  1.6M  1.6G   1% /run
 /dev/sda2       219G  113G   95G  55% /
 tmpfs           7.8G   40M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
 tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
 tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 /dev/sda1       511M  7.3M  504M   2% /boot/efi
 /dev/sdd1       458G   87G  348G  20% /mnt/usb500
 /dev/sdb1       1.8T  144G  1.6T   9% /mnt/usb2T
 /dev/sdc1       293G  132G  147G  48% /mnt/usb250
 tmpfs           1.6G   52K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
 pCloud.fs       2.0T  106G  1.9T   6% /home/stephen/pCloudDrive
```

output of `df -i` as requested in comments:

```
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             2029639    583   2029056    1% /dev
tmpfs            2037540    965   2036575    1% /run
/dev/sda2       14622720 537713  14085007    4% /
tmpfs            2037540    211   2037329    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2037540      5   2037535    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            2037540     18   2037522    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sdd1       30531584  84224  30447360    1% /mnt/usb500
/dev/sdb1      122101760 205683 121896077    1% /mnt/usb2T
/dev/sdc1       19537920    547  19537373    1% /mnt/usb250
tmpfs            2037540     35   2037505    1% /run/user/1000
pCloud.fs              0      0         0     - /home/stephen/pCloudDrive
```

Maximum watches allowed:

```
sysctl -n fs.inotify.max_user_watches
8192
```

`pgrep -f notify` shows only one watch.

Comment: What does `df -f` and `findmnt` show?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I believe you mean `df -i `

Comment: Also, check this pynotify FAQ https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor added to question

Comment: @JucaPirama added to question

Comment: is the watch in the `clouddrive`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No it is not in the `clouddrive` .However it was once when I first encountered the problem. Thinking the issue may be  related, I then removed it from the clouddrive but that did not solve the problem. Also - stopping the pcloud process does not solve the problem.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Ah. So I find that closing the pcloud application, and even killing the pcloud processes, does not completely shut down pcloud. I had to `pgrep -f pcloud |xargs sudo kill` Once all pcloud processes had been shut down I can start the notify. I can then restart pcloud and all is well.

Comment: Create an answer with this info and mark as choosed, so others can benefit from it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points in this issue based purely on experimentation and observation. This is **not** based on familiarity with pCloud code or on extensive exploration of pCloud documentation, however it appears that:

1. pCloud does not support inotify (pyinotify is a wrapper for the linux inotify application) and in this case, the target directory for the notify process had once been placed into the pCloudDrive.
2. *Behavior suggests that* pCloud holds a reference to files once included in its drive and that to free these files it is necessary to kill all pCloud processes. A reboot does not work because pCloud persists its references through a system reset.

It is necessary to kill all pCloud processes, and for me a complete cleanup required intervention from the root account. Note that pCloud processes run as `pcloud` and `pCloud`(different case)

So use:

```
pgrep -fi pcloud | xargs kill
```

Once the pCloud processes have been cleared  you can start your watch. You can then restart pCloud and it will not restore its references.